# pgfplots and log scale: bars starting from the bottom of the screen

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

The following MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,ymode = log]
\addplot coordinates{
(1,1e-15)
(2,1e-14)
(3,1e-13)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

compiles to this bar chart:

[image]

I'd like the bars to start from the bottom of the screen instead of the top, since it makes more sense to visualize my data like that (they are computational errors).

Is there a pgfplots option to achieve that? The manual only says that the bars always start from 0 (and there is no way to change that); clearly, when `ymode=log` this is interpreted as starting from log(1)=0, which is not what I want here.

Comment: You can set `log origin=infty` to make the bars start from the bottom.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I missed that on the manual! Wish to post it as an answer for me to accept it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define where the "drawing origin" for logarithmic plots should be by setting `log origin` to either `0` or `infty`. If you set it to `0`, which is the default, bar plots, comb plots and filled area plots will start from `log(1)=0`, so in this case the top of the plot. If you set it to `infty`, the plots will start from the bottom edge of the plot area, which is what you want in this case:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,ymode = log, log origin=infty]
\addplot coordinates{
(1,1e-15)
(2,1e-14)
(3,1e-13)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```